# Is it possible to combine multiple conditions inside an expect in React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

For example, there are two expect conditions like these:

```
expect(firstItem).toHaveClass(firstStyle);
expect(firstItem).not.toHaveClass(secondStyle);
```

Is there a way to make them in one line? Something like:

```
expect(firstItem).toHaveClass(firstStyle).and.not.toHaveClass(secondStyle);
```